# Add custom attribute without a value jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do i add custom attribute without a value jQuery? I want the following:

```
    <tr data-header-row>
```

The following does not work:

```
  $(tr).prop('data-header-row',true);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add HTML element attributes in jQuery you need to use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
$(tr).attr('data-header-row','true');
```

But I would suggest you to use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method instead:

```
$(tr).data('header-row', true);
```

It will automatically add `data-` namespace to your attribute.

To get stored value then you can do simple:

```
console.log( $(tr).data('header-row') );
```

Comment: `.data()` does not actually add an attribute, just saves the value and links it to the element in a jQuery internal cache.

Comment: Hello. That did not work. .attr puts an attribute with a value of true. I do not want that.

Comment: @Spokey correct, but using `data` you can grab attributes values without adding an preffix.

Comment: @BoundForGlory and what do you want then?

Comment: @BoundForGlory if you want to have just attribute you can pass an empty string to it: `$(tr).attr('data-header-row','');`

Comment: @antyrat - How do i add custom attribute without a value via jQuery? Just like my question title says.

Comment: @BoundForGlory see my comment above

Comment: @antyrat - $(tr).attr('data-header-row','') worked. Thanks :)